# Modification of Pearson's Chi-square test

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, multinomial-distribution

At first glance, Pearson's chi-squared test seems flawed in a major way. Can you help me identify the error in my logic?

I have a multinomial distribution with $k$ outcomes, and $p_i$ denotes the hypothesized probability of outcome $i$. I obtain $n$ samples from this distribution, and let $n_i$ denote the number of times I observe outcome $i$ (so $\sum n_i=n$).

We have $E[n_i]=np_i$, $Var[n_i]=np_i(1-p_i)$ and $Cov[n_i,n_j]=-np_ip_j$ for $i\ne j$. Setting $x_i:=\frac{n_i-np_i}{\sqrt{np_i(1-p_i)}}$, we have $E[x_i]=0$, $Var[x_i]=1$ and
$Cov[x_i,x_j]=-\sqrt{\frac{p_ip_j}{(1-p_i)(1-p_j)}}$.

Let $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^k$ be the vector of $x_i$s, so $E[\vec{x}]=\vec{0}$ and
$Var[\vec{x}]_{i,j}=Cov[x_i,x_j]$, which was calculated above. This covariance matrix has corank $1$ (this is easier to show before rescaling, and can include a proof in future edits if requested). If the $n_i$ are all sufficiently large, the distribution of each $x_i$ is roughly $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. But $Var[\vec{x}]$ *does not* depend on $n$, and is really not that close to the identity matrix (especially if $k$ is small), so the $x_i$ are not uncorrelated and do not become any less correlated if $n$ is taken to be larger and larger.

And yet we estimate $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} x^2_i\sim \chi^2_{k-1}$ to test this hypothesis. The choice of not including $x^2_k$ is itself quite strange, because while it is true that $x_k$ completely depends on the other $x_i$, we've ignored their correlations in every other context! And isn't there an easy fix here?

Let $A$ be a $(k-1)\times k$ matrix with $ACov[\vec{x}]A^T=I_{k-1}$, the $(k-1)\times (k-1)$ identity matrix (which can be computed via e.g. SVD). Then $Var[A\vec{x}]=I_{k-1}$. As $n$ gets very large the distribution of the components of $A\vec{x}$ individually approach $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and their correlation matrix is the identity. This doesn't imply that their joint distribution approaches the joint gaussian distribution (as uncorrelated guassians are not necessarily independent), but I would imagine this is provably true.

And so why don't we test $\|A\vec{x}\|^2\sim \chi_{k-1}^2$ instead? This $A$ is not hard to compute as its complexity is in terms of $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know the Pearson test uses:

$$X_i = \frac{n_i - np_i}{\sqrt{np_i}}$$ and not the $X_i$ that you mentioned. To prove the result of the Pearson test, let $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n = \frac1n \begin{pmatrix}n_1\\\vdots\\n_k\end{pmatrix}$ and $\boldsymbol{\theta} = \begin{pmatrix}p_1\\\vdots\\p_k\end{pmatrix}$ you can easily prove that

$$\sqrt{n} \left(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n - \boldsymbol{\theta}\right) \overset{d}\to \mathcal N\left(\boldsymbol{0}, \Sigma\right)$$

where $$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
p_1\left(1-p_1\right) & -p_1p_2  & \cdots & -p_1p_k\\
-p_1p_2 & p_2\left(1-p_2\right) & \cdots & -p_2p_k\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
-p_1p_n & -p_2p_k & \cdots & p_k\left(1-p_k\right)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $\boldsymbol{A} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac1{\sqrt{p_1}} & \\ & \ddots \\ &&\frac1{\sqrt{p_k}}\end{bmatrix}$ then, $$\sqrt{n}\boldsymbol{A} \left(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n - \boldsymbol{\theta}\right) \overset{d}\to \mathcal N\left(\boldsymbol{0}, \boldsymbol{A}\Sigma\boldsymbol{A}^\intercal\right)$$

You can observe that $$\boldsymbol{X} = \sqrt{n}\boldsymbol{A} \left(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n - \boldsymbol{\theta}\right) $$

and if $\boldsymbol{u} = \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{p_1}\\\vdots\\\sqrt{p_k}\end{pmatrix}$ then $$\boldsymbol{A}\Sigma\boldsymbol{A}^\intercal = \mathbf I - \boldsymbol{u}\boldsymbol{u}^\intercal$$

Finally

$$\boldsymbol{X} \overset{d}\to \mathcal N\left(\boldsymbol{0}, \mathbf I - \boldsymbol{u}\boldsymbol{u}^\intercal\right)$$ Since $\boldsymbol{u}^{\intercal} \boldsymbol{X}= 0$ then if $Z\sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$ then $$\boldsymbol{X} + Z\boldsymbol{u} \overset{d}\to \mathcal N(0, \mathbf I).$$

By [Cochran's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem), $$\left\|X\right\|^2 = \left\|\pi_{\boldsymbol{u}^\perp}\left(\boldsymbol{X} + Z\boldsymbol{u}\right)\right\|^2 \sim \chi^2_{k-1}$$

Comment: Beautiful; thank you. I suspect this implies that there is a very nice ``diagonal" $A$ satisfying the conditions of my question, to make it equivalent to the Pearson chi-square test

Comment: Probably. So your question has another test different from the one of Pearson? Is that right?

Comment: Based on your answer, I'm sure that the two are equivalent. $A$ will probably correct the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-p_i}}$ difference.